# Useful, non-trivial general theorems about morphisms of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

I apologize in advance as this is not a research level question but rather one which could benefit from expert attention but is potentially useful mainly to novice mathematicians.

I'm trying to compile a list of non-obvious theorems about morphisms of schemes which are useful for general intuition but whose proofs are not easy/technical. Here are some examples:

> **Zariski's Main Theorem:** Let $Y$ be quasi-compact, separated and $f:X \to Y$ be separated, quasi-finite, finitely presented. Then there is a factorization $X \to Z \to Y$ where the first map is an open immersion and the second is finite. **Mnemonic: *(quasi-finite)*** $\sim$ **(finite)** $\circ$ **(open immersion)**

---

> **Nagata's compactification theorem:** Let $S$ be qcqs and $f:X \to S$ be separated, finite type. Then $X$ densely embeds into a proper $S$-scheme.**Mnemonic: *non-horrible schemes have compactifications***

---

> **Temkin's factorization theorem**: Let $Y$ be qcqs and $f: X \to Y$ be separated, quasi-compact. Then there's a factorization $X \to Z \to Y$ with the first being affine and the second proper. **Mnemonic: *(separated + quasicompact) = (proper)*** $\circ$ **(affine)**.

---

> **Chow's lemma:** Let $S$ be noetherian and $f: X \to S$ separated finite type. Then there exists a projective, surjective $S$-morphism $\bar{X} \to X$ which is an isomorphism on a dense subset and where $\bar{X} \to S$ is quasi-projective. Moreover $X$ is proper iff $\bar{X}$ is projective, and if $X$ is reduced $\bar{X}$ can be chosen to be so as well. **Mnemonic: *reasonable schemes have quasi-projective "replacements" and proper schemes have projective "replacements"***

---

Hopefully it's clear now what I'm looking for. All theorems above have very weak assumptions and very satisfying conclusions. These are what I'm after.

Comment: How about something like Chevalley's theorem? It says that a quasi-compact morphism which is locally of finite type preserves locally constructible sets.

Comment: You could add Stein factorization to the list: (proper) = (integral) $\circ$ (proper with connected geometric fibers). http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GX

Comment: In your statement of Chow's lemma you could replace noetherian by qcqs.

Comment: Open immersion = etale + monic (EGA IV$_4$, 17.9.1+epsilon), integral morphism = affine + universally closed (EGA IV$_4$, 18.12.8), closed immersion = proper monomorphism (EGA IV$_4$, 18.12.6), qcqs = relatively affine over finite type Z-scheme (Thomason-Trobaugh, Theorem C.9), relative ampleness for a proper fp map is fibral (EGA IV$_3$, 9.6.5), lfp map is unramifed iff etale-locally a closed immersion (EGA IV$_4$, 17.7.1, 18.8.3), qc separated map is immersion iff monic + Mochizuki's valuative criterion (Ch. I, sec. 2.4 of his book on p-adic Teichmuller theory in noetherian case).

Comment: Finitely presented flat map is finite iff quasi-finite & separated with locally constant fiber rank (II, 1.19 Deligne-Rapoport in noetherian case), lfp = commutes with "expected" limits (EGA IV$_3$, 8.14.2), valuative criterion for flatness over a reduced base (EGA IV$_3$, 11.8.1 in noetherian case with dvr's, 4.2.10 in Part I of Raynaud-Gruson in general), universal schematic dominance/density is fibral  under "expected" flatness hypotheses (EGA IV$_3$, 11.10.9, 11.10.10), any flat lfp cover admits a section over a *locally quasi-finite* & *flat* lfp cover (EGA IV$_4$, 17.16.2).

Comment: Somoth/étale morphisms can be lifted (Zariski-locally on the source) along closed immersions (EGA IV_4, 18.1.1).

Comment: I like Zariski-Nagata purity theorem: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant and quasi-finite morphism between integral schemes. Suppose that $X$ is normal and $Y$ is regular and locally noetherian, and let $Z$ be the set of points of $X$ where $f$ is not étale. Then either $X=Z$ or $Z$ is of pure codimension 1. (See SGA1, Exposé X, Théorème 3.1)

Mnemonic: "the ramification locus of quasi-finite dominant morphisms is a divisor if the base is smooth"

Answer (score 15):

Here's a theorem I find useful:

> > **Theorem.** Let $\phi \colon X \to Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes of relative dimension $d$. Then there exists an open cover $X = \bigcup U_i$ of $X$ such that each $U_i \to Y$ factors as
> >     $$U_i \stackrel \pi \to \mathbb A^d_Y \to Y,$$
> >     with $\pi$ étale. **Mnemonic: smooth morphisms have étale coordinates.**

See [Tag 054L](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/054L).

Comment: EGA 4 vol. 4 Corollary 17.11.4 expresses this as a necessary and sufficient criterion for a map to be smooth at a point.

Comment: Shouldn't the $d_i$'s be constant here?

Comment: @SaalHardali: they are (automatically) locally constant.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes that's what I meant. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Under the same conditions, how likely would you say is the existence of a factorization $X \to E \to Y$ where the first map is etale and $E$ is some vector bundle over $Y$?

Comment: @SaalHardali: there is no global statement like that (think about the case $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Of course! I should have thought of that. Thanks